# How can I patch a ConfigParser key/value?

Tags: python, python-unittest, configparser, python-mock

When I use the following code:

```
from unittest import mock
import configparser

configtext = '''
[SECTION]
whatever=True
'''

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_string(configtext)


def test_fails():
    expected_value = 'fnord'
    with mock.patch.dict(config, {'db': expected_value}):
        assert config['db'] is expected_value
```

My test fails because `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`.

This is not at all what I expected. Obviously I would expect it to set the value like I want... but apparently config is only dict-ish, unfortunately.

How can I patch this so `config['db']` is the value I want, just for the lifetime of my test?

Comment: What are you actually trying to test, here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm actually doing something else, but this is the most MVCE ;)

Comment: Well then it's not a terribly helpful example! Please give a [mcve] of the code under test, too.

Comment: The code under test is not failing - the `mock.patch.dict` call is failing.

Comment: You're calling `mock.patch.dict`, but `config` is not a dictionary (and it's barely dictionary-like).  If you would stop being cagey about what you're actually trying to test we might be able to provide suggestions about better ways to go about it.  In this situation, it's not clear why you're even using mock (just set the option in the config object!).

Comment: @larsks because I want it automatically set back to whatever it was before I started my test. I'm not trying to be cagey, it just wasn't my problem. I understand completely how to test the thing I'm trying to test. My problem is that I want to access my config via `config['db']`, and mock that value in my test case, and mocking the value isn't working. But, considering what I discovered (see my self-answer), it looks like I will have to take an alternate approach. But that's a different question entirely, and not what I wanted to know here ;)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the problem is that I had a slight misunderstanding. Although `ConfigParser` *looks* dict-like, it isn't actually. The stack trace holds evidence of this:

```
    def test_fails():
        expected_value = 'whatever'
>       with mock.patch.dict(config, {'db': expected_value}):

test.py:15: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py:1593: in __enter__
    self._patch_dict()
/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py:1619: in _patch_dict
    in_dict[key] = values[key]
/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py:969: in __setitem__
    self.read_dict({key: value})
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <configparser.ConfigParser object at 0x7f1be6d20f98>, dictionary = {'db': 'whatever'}
source = '<dict>'
```

Note that it's trying to do a `read_dict` here. That's because it's expecting to have a [section-ish](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#customizing-parser-behaviour) format:

```
>>> parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> parser.read_dict({'section1': {'key1': 'value1',
...                                'key2': 'value2',
...                                'key3': 'value3'},
...                   'section2': {'keyA': 'valueA',
...                                'keyB': 'valueB',
...                                'keyC': 'valueC'},
...                   'section3': {'foo': 'x',
...                                'bar': 'y',
...                                'baz': 'z'}
... })
```

<sup><sub>From the docs</sub></sup>

Having a single-key access is not possible. To get this example to work, you have to do the following:

```
with mock.patch.dict(config, {'db': {'db': expected_value}}):
    # rest of code
```

Note: Values will be converted to their stringish counterparts. So if you are trying to store an actual database connection (or similar) here, it won't work.